# Finding mean, count and std for four rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm calculating the mean, number of observations and standard deviations for 4 rows in a pandas dataframe. Right now I do it making a new dataframe but there must be an easier way than using four lines? I thought I could use groupby and then agg but I have been unable to make it work

```
stats = pd.DataFrame()
stats["mean"] = df.mean(axis=1)
stats["count"] = df.count(axis=1)
stats["std"] = df.std(axis=1)
```

Comment: Your code calculates the stats row-wise for all the *columns* of `df`. How does that relate to "4 rows"?

Comment: Do you want it to be a new dataframe, or do you want extra columns in original?

Comment: What about something like:

`stats.iloc[0:4].describe()` ?

Comment: I think all of these would be part of the output of `df.describe()`

Comment: Aryerez: I have a dataframe with 4 rows and 100 columns. I want to calculate the mean, count (which is 100) and std.dev for the four rows over the 100 colums, i.e. I want a dataframe consistent of four mean values, 4 count values and 4 std.dev

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of what your original dataframe `df` looks like, but maybe what you are looking for is the [`describe()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) ?
It returns a whole bunch of useful statistics (including *mean*, *count* and *std*) for each of your dataframe's Series that has numeric values.

EDIT : Since apparently you are computing theses statistics over rows and not columns, you might want to [`transpose()` your dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) before applying `describe()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randn(10) for i in range(5)])
df.agg(['mean', 'std', 'count'], axis=1)
```

If you want stats on column vise use `axis=0`

Comment: `TypeError: ("'list' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it later today and come back with a reply

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
for func in ['mean', 'std', 'count']:
    df[func] = eval('df.loc[:, cols].' + func + '(axis=1)')
```

Comment: There must be an easier way than making a for loop? Think that is exactly what I want to avoid? Usually pyhton has different ways to make code simpler, I believe?

Comment: @MikaelOlaiMilhøj There is no problem using a loop that iterates the actions you want to do, and it is much better than writing a line for each action. What is to avoid is iterating over the rows of a `dataframe` which is not a all what I'm suggesting.